# Where in (sub query) or (list) performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to make a list based on whether a field in the original table is in two lists.  My code is thus:

```
SELECT *
FROM ListofPlaces
WHERE Property = 'MODERATE'
    and (HOMELAND in (
        SELECT distinct HOMELAND
        FROM PLANS
        WHERE left(plans.code, 1) = '1') 
    or HOMELAND in (
        'PlaceA'
        , 'PlaceB'
        , 'PlaceC'
        , 'PlaceD'
        , 'PlaceE'))
```

The list and the sub query will work fine individually, taking 00:00:01.43 for the sub query and 00:00:00.13 for the list, however they take around a min once combined.

I have tried using a left join, but this leads to a more significant reduction in performance.

The table 'PLANS' is a larger table of 4M+ rows, whilst list of places is less than 1000.

My question is whether I'm using the and/or operators efficiently, and if so, is there a more efficient way to run this query?

Comment: If there exists index on `code` try `plans.code like '1%'` instead of `left(plans.code, 1) = '1'`

Comment: Don't know if it makes a difference in performance, but `distinct` can be left out. And I agree with @Serg that `like '1%'` is likely to beat `left(...`, probably even without an index on plans.code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rewriting this using `UNION`:

```
SELECT *
FROM ListofPlaces
WHERE Property = 'MODERATE' AND
      HOMELAND IN (SELECT HOMELAND
                   FROM PLANS
                   WHERE left(plans.code, 1) = '1'
                  ) 
UNION
SELECT *
FROM ListofPlaces
WHERE Property = 'MODERATE' AND
      HOMELAND in ('PlaceA', 'PlaceB', 'PlaceC', 'PlaceD', 'PlaceE');
```

The optimizer can sometimes be confused by `OR`s.  `UNION` may be needed here instead of `UNION ALL` if the two lists contain similar elements.  Otherwise, if you know they are disjoint, use `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not join?

```
SELECT LoP.*
FROM ListofPlaces LoP
left join PLANS Pl
  on LoP.HOMELAND = Pl.HOMELAND
WHERE Property = 'MODERATE'
    and (left(plans.code, 1) = '1' 
    or LoP.HOMELAND in (
        'PlaceA'
        , 'PlaceB'
        , 'PlaceC'
        , 'PlaceD'
        , 'PlaceE'))
```

Comment: This was my second thought too john, unfortunately the performance is also poor- thanks for the help though